# I wanted to split my data into 2 columns however, I faced a problem splitting it

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I got this after I run my code. There isn't an error in my code but the output that I received isn't what I wanted.

```
Sub splitcolumns()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim result As Variant
    
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        'Split Location into 2 Columns
        txt = Cells(i, 1).Value
        result = Split(txt, ",")

        For j = 0 To UBound(result)
            Cells(3, 3 + j).Value = result(j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

The output that I wanted is

[image]

Comment: Try `Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = result(j)`

Comment: im able to garner the header only. I got run time error 9: Subscript out of range

Comment: Works for me.  What line gives the error, and what's the value of the array index when it fails?

Comment: It highlights Cells(i, 3+j).Value =result(j) as an error. Array (3,4) is where it stops

Comment: If you hover over `i` and `j` what are their values?

Comment: When it stops and you click Debug, what are the values of `i` and `j` ?

Comment: the values are j=1 , i =3

Comment: Working fine for me with your posted data

Comment: just to clarirfy the code is like that:                     LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        'Split Location into 2 Columns
        txt = Cells(i, 1).Value
        result = Split(txt, ",")

        For j = 0 To LastRow
            Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = result(j)
        Next j
    Next i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```vb
Sub splitcolumns()
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    For i = 3 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        arr = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ",") 'Split Location by comma

        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Cells(i, 3 + j).Value = arr(j)
        Next j
    
    Next i
End Sub
```

Output is in red:

[image]